# Что значит термин "обвязка" в контексте сис. администрирования?

Tags: linux, ос

Например, "... масса приложений использует обвязку из init.d для работы с pid'ом ..."

Comment: Очевидно, дополнительный функционал, работающий с приложением как с черной коробкой (т.е. не зная, что лежит внутри него и как оно работает).

Comment: одно из направлений, так называемой, BDSM-методолгии сис. администрирования

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я думаю, что в процитированном [комментарии с habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129207/#comment_4275905) под термином «обвязка» подразумевался набор вспомогательных *shell*-функций.

подобные наборы используются системами инициализации и конфигурирования. пара примеров:

- [lsb init script functions](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptfunc.html) — в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах это файл `/lib/lsb/init-functions`.
- [initramfs helper functions](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/kernel/initramfs-tools.git/tree/scripts/functions) — находятся в `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions` и копируются внутрь [*initrd*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) при его создании.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понимаю, имеется в виду более широкий контекст. Обвязкой (boilerplate) называется (достаточно длинный) код, который необходимо применить для того, чтобы воспользоваться какой-либо фичей.

Допустим, для того, чтобы вызвать правильно вызвать какую-либо функцию, нужно получить код ошибки от неё, и правильно его обработать. И параметры нужно упаковать в сложную структуру.

```
struct complicated_function_parameters par;
complicated_function_parameters_init(&par);
par.p1 = "hello";
struct error_data ed;
while (!complicated_function(&par, &ed))
{
    if (!ed.retry)
    {
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Так вот, весь код, кроме вызова функции, считается обвязочным: его цель состоит лишь в том, чтобы эту самую функцию правильно вызвать.